# Maven ant, move all content of a name directory in the subdirectory

Tags: java, maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

I have an unknown structure such as

```
folder/folder1/XXX/file1
folder/folder1/XXX/file2
folder/folder21/folder22/XXX/file2
```

and i would like to get something like

```
/folder1/file1
/folder1/file2
/folder21/folder22/file2
```

In a script ssh i would simply do :

```
find -type d -name XXX -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && mv *.* ../"  \;
find -type d -name XXX -delete
```

Is it doable using an ant task ?

Comment: By “unknown structure” do you mean that XXX directories could exist in any number of places in a file tree, which aren’t known ahead of time?

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution using a regexpmapper:

```
                <configuration>
                    <target name="copy XXX files to the parent directory">
                        <!-- move all files in XXX/ folder to the parent folder-->
                        <move todir="directory">
                            <fileset dir=directory">
                                <include name="**/XXX/*"/>
                            </fileset>
                            <mapper type="regexp" from="^(.*)XXX(.*)" to="\1/\2"/>
                        </move>
                        <!-- Remove empty folders-->
                        <delete includeemptydirs="true">
                            <fileset dir="directory">
                                <and>
                                    <size value="0"/>
                                    <type type="dir"/>
                                </and>
                            </fileset>
                        </delete>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
```